# Datatable with column expression

Tags: vb.net, datatable, ado.net, expression

I'm trying to use datatable columns with expression but when a load data, some columns works and other shows "Cannot perform '*' operation on System.Double and System.String"

I use this procedure in vb.net

1. Load datatable from datareader
2. Assign previous load expressions to defined columns
3. List items in html table

I’m using this dataset with data between of columns with Expression.

[image]

Can you help me?

UPDATE:

typo: instead of IVA in the first appearance I mean IVAP, the next column name IVA is correct

the image is data copied from SQL management studio over excel with explains about the situation

this is my code

```
            Dim dtFinalData As New DataTable("DataProcessed")

            For i As Integer = 1 To objReader.FieldCount - 1

                    Dim cColumName As DataColumn = New DataColumn
                    With cDiff
                        .DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Double")
                        .ColumnName = objReader.GetName(i).ToString()
                    End With
                    dtFinalData.Columns.Add(cColumName)

            Next

            Dim cColWithExpression1 As DataColumn = New DataColumn
            With cColWithExpression1
                .DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Double")
                .ColumnName = "PCONDT"
                .Expression = "PSINIVA - (PSINIVA * (Discount/100))"
            End With
            dtFinalData.Columns.Add(cColWithExpression1)

            Dim cColWithExpression2 As DataColumn = New DataColumn
            With cColWithExpression2
                .DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Double")
                .ColumnName = "Ivap"
                .Expression = "(PCONIVA-PCONDT)*Units"
            End With
            dtFinalData.Columns.Add(cColWithExpression2)

            Dim cCol As DataColumn = New DataColumn
            With cCol
                .DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Double")
                .ColumnName = "IVA"
                .DefaultValue = 21
            End With
            dtFinalData.Columns.Add(cCol)                   

            Dim cColWithExpression3 As DataColumn = New DataColumn
            With cColWithExpression3
                .DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Double")
                .ColumnName = "PCONIVA"
                .Expression = "(PCONDT*(1+(IVA/100)))"
            End With
            dtFinalData.Columns.Add(cColWithExpression3)    

            If objReader.HasRows Then
                While objReader.Read()
                        Dim RecordRow As DataRow = dtFinalData.NewRow
                        
                        RecordRow("Units") = objReader.Item("Units")
                        RecordRow("PSINIVA") = objReader.Item("PSINIVA")
                        RecordRow("PU") = objReader.Item("PU")
                        RecordRow("IVA") = objReader.Item("IVA")
                        dtFinalData.Rows.Add(RecordRow)
                End While
            End If
```

UPDATE 2 - SOLVED (I think)

Thanks everyone for the answers, I found the procedure to work with the cascade of column expression, in datatable

1. Create datatable with column names and numeric data type . In my case UNITS, PSINIVA, PU, DISCOUNT, IVA (I adjust my data source which is in a SQLDatareader to add IVA data column from database)
2. Add values from data source
3. Add columns definition with name, data type and the specific formula (Expression) but in sequence, where the previously column complete their data before the next formula. In my case first expression column must be PCONDT, next EXENT, next PCONIVA, and final IVAP

Using parts of the original code (perhaps not so performant), this is the final code

```
        Dim dtFinalData As New DataTable("DataProcessed")

        For i As Integer = 1 To objReader.FieldCount - 1

                Dim cColumName As DataColumn = New DataColumn
                With cDiff
                    .DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Double")
                    .ColumnName = objReader.GetName(i).ToString()
                End With
                dtFinalData.Columns.Add(cColumName)

        Next
        
        If objReader.HasRows Then
            While objReader.Read()
                    Dim RecordRow As DataRow = dtFinalData.NewRow
                    RecordRow("Units") = objReader.Item("Units")
                    RecordRow("PSINIVA") = objReader.Item("PSINIVA")
                    RecordRow("PU") = objReader.Item("PU")
                    RecordRow("Discount") = objReader.Item("Discount")
                    RecordRow("IVA") = objReader.Item("IVA")
                    dtFinalData.Rows.Add(RecordRow)
            End While
        End If      
           
        Dim cColWithExpression1 As DataColumn = New DataColumn
        With cColWithExpression1
            .DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Double")
            .ColumnName = "PCONDT"
            .Expression = "PSINIVA - (PSINIVA * (Discount/100))"
        End With
        dtFinalData.Columns.Add(cColWithExpression1)

        Dim cColWithExpression2 As DataColumn = New DataColumn
        With cColWithExpression2
            .DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Double")
            .ColumnName = "EXENT"
            .Expression = "IIF(IVA=0,PCONDT*Units,0) "
        End With
        dtFinalData.Columns.Add(cColWithExpression2)

        Dim cColWithExpression3 As DataColumn = New DataColumn
        With cColWithExpression3
            .DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Double")
            .ColumnName = "PCONIVA"
            .Expression = "(PCONDT*(1+(IVA/100)))"
        End With
        dtFinalData.Columns.Add(cColWithExpression3)    


        Dim cColWithExpression4 As DataColumn = New DataColumn
        With cColWithExpression4
            .DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Double")
            .ColumnName = "Ivap"
            .Expression = "(PCONIVA-PCONDT)*Units"
        End With
        dtFinalData.Columns.Add(cColWithExpression4)
```

This is how data appears, after this code
[image]

Comment: Why are you trying to perform arithmetic on text? If the data is actually numeric then why isn't it in a numeric column?

Comment: I suspect that the issue is how you're creating and populating the `DataTable`, so please show us that. My guess is that it's Excel choosing text for a column that isn't fully populated with numbers.

Comment: User18387401 all numbers data are i'm system.double datatype. In this case the expresión are using post sql transacción to give the user dynamics calculations

Comment: @John offers good advice. Seeing your DataTable code will go a long way toward our ability to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I added additional  information to this post

Comment: For the record, the code to add the columns to the table could be far more succinct and type-safe. The `Add` method is overloaded so there's no need to create the `DataColumn` first. Also, use the `GetType` operator rather than the `Type.GetType` method. E.g. `dtFinalData.Columns.Add("PCONDT", GetType(Double), "PSINIVA - (PSINIVA * (Discount/100))")`. Those overloads return the `DataColumn` object, so you can set other properties directly, e.g. `dtFinalData.Columns.Add("IVA", GetType(Double)).DefaultValue = 21`.

Comment: There should also be no need to loop over your data reader, if all the columns match up. The `DataTable` has a `Load` method that you can pass the data reader to as an argument. It will then map data from the data reader to columns of the same name in the `DataTable`.

Comment: I suggest that you debug that code and actually look at the data as you read it, as well as perform those calculations yourself. It's hard to say exactly where the issue is but that's why VS includes a debugger.

Comment: I can't help but be curious... have you considered and for some reason decided against using Visual Studio's in-built `DataSet` tool? With it you can accomplish all you're trying to do here in a matter of mere minutes.

Comment: InteXX Thanks for your suggestions, I'm using this way of coding because it's a mandatory requirement of my client.

Comment: @john thanks for your comments, in this case load directly from datareader was the origin of this situation.

Comment: Well... you need to talk your client out of that. The client doesn't always know best. That's why he relies on you. If he wants bad code he can write it himself 

Answer (score 0):

It appears your PCONDT and PCONIVA columns are of type `String`. Change them to a numeric type and your formulas should work.

Comment: InteXX thanks for tour answer. The numbers column are in datatype sistem.double befere the assign of expression

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Visual Studio's in-built `DataSet` tool instead. With it you can easily accomplish all that you've described, with much less effort.

[image]

For example, here's the definition for the `PCONDT` column:

[image]

This code:

```
Private Sub TestDataSet()
  Dim oTable As Test.Db.DataProcessedDataTable
  Dim oRow1 As Test.Db.DataProcessedRow
  Dim oRow2 As Test.Db.DataProcessedRow
  Dim oDb As Test.Db

  oDb = New Test.Db
  oTable = oDb.DataProcessed
  oRow1 = oTable.NewDataProcessedRow
  oRow2 = oTable.NewDataProcessedRow

  oRow1.Units = 2
  oRow1.PSINIVA = 20
  oRow1.PU = 20
  oRow1.Discount = 10
  oRow1.IVA = 21

  oRow2.Units = 1
  oRow2.PSINIVA = 100
  oRow2.PU = 100
  oRow2.Discount = 0
  oRow2.IVA = 21

  oTable.AddDataProcessedRow(oRow1)
  oTable.AddDataProcessedRow(oRow2)

  oDb.WriteXml("Db.xml")
End Sub
```

...produces this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Db xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Db.xsd">
  <DataProcessed>
    <Units>2</Units>
    <PSINIVA>20</PSINIVA>
    <PU>20</PU>
    <Discount>10</Discount>
    <IVA>21</IVA>
    <PCONDT>18</PCONDT>
    <EXENT>0</EXENT>
    <PCONIVA>21.78</PCONIVA>
    <Ivap>7.560000000000002</Ivap>
  </DataProcessed>
  <DataProcessed>
    <Units>1</Units>
    <PSINIVA>100</PSINIVA>
    <PU>100</PU>
    <Discount>0</Discount>
    <IVA>21</IVA>
    <PCONDT>100</PCONDT>
    <EXENT>0</EXENT>
    <PCONIVA>121</PCONIVA>
    <Ivap>21</Ivap>
  </DataProcessed>
</Db>
```

...which is, I believe, your desired result.

This approach has the added benefit of eliminating the [Magic Strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_string) from your code.